# Slick insert into H2, but no data inserted

Tags: scala, h2, slick

I'm sure I am missing something really stupidly obvious here - I have a unit test for a very simple Slick 3.2 setup. The DAO has basic retrieve and insert methods as follows:

```
  override def questions: Future[Seq[Tables.QuestionRow]] =
    db.run(Question.result)

  override def createQuestion(title: String, body: String, authorUuid: UUID): Future[Long] =
    db.run(Question returning Question.map(_.id) += QuestionRow(0l, UUID.randomUUID().toString, title, body, authorUuid.toString))
```

And I have some unit tests - for the tests im using in memory H2 and have a setup script (passed to the jdbcurl) to initialise two basic rows in the table.

The unit tests for retriving works fine, and they fetch the two rows inserted by the init script, and I have just added a simple unit test to create a row and then retrieve them all - assuming it will fetch the three rows, but no matter what I do, it only ever retrieves the initial two:

```
  it should "create a new question" in {
    whenReady(questionDao.createQuestion("Question three", "some body", UUID.randomUUID)) { s =>
      whenReady(questionDao.questions(s)) { q =>
        println(s)
        println(q.map(_.title))
        assert(true)
      }
    }
  }
```

The output shows that the original `s` (the returning ID from the autoinc) is 3, as I would expect (I have also tried the insert not doing the returning step and just letting it return the number of rows inserted, which returns 1, as expecteD), but looking at the values returned in `q`, its only ever the first two rows inserted by the init script.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My assumptions are that your JDBC url is something like `jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'init.sql'` and  no connection pooling is used.

There are two scenarios:

1. the connection is performed with `keepAliveConnection = true` (or by appending `DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1` to the JDBC url) and the `init.sql` is something like:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS QUESTION;
CREATE TABLE QUESTION(...);
INSERT INTO QUESTION VALUES(null, ...);
INSERT INTO QUESTION VALUES(null, ...);
```

2. the connection is performed with `keepAliveConnection = false` (default) (without appending `DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1` to the JDBC url) and the `init.sql` is something like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE QUESTION(...);
INSERT INTO QUESTION VALUES(null, ...);
INSERT INTO QUESTION VALUES(null, ...);
```

---

The call to `questionDao.createQuestion` will open a new connection to your H2 database and will trigger the initialization script (`init.sql`).

In both scenarios, right after this call, the database contains a `QUESTION` table with 2 rows.

In scenario (2) after this call the connection is closed and according to H2 [documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases):

> By default, closing the last connection to a database closes the database. For an in-memory database, this means the content is lost. To keep the database open, add ;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1 to the database URL. To keep the content of an in-memory database as long as the virtual machine is alive, use jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1.

The call to `questionDao.questions` will then open **a new** connection to your H2 database and will trigger **again** the initialization script (`init.sql`).

In scenario (1) the first connection is kept alive (and also the database content) but the new connection will re-execute the initialization script (`init.sql`) erasing the database content.

Given that (in both scenarios) `questionDao.createQuestion` returns `3`, as expected, but then the content is lost and so the subsequent call to `questionDao.questions` will use a freshly initialized database.

Comment: thanks! I was experimenting with the runscript notation and had deleted the close delay flag!

Comment: same problem resolved adding the close delay  and removing **;INIT=runscript from 'classpath:sql/init_script'**